# Why do I have libdrm-amdgpu1 and libdrm-radeon1 folders?

Tags: drivers, intel, kubuntu, amd-graphics, radeon

Why do I have libdrm-amdgpu1 and libdrm-radeon1 folders? My HP Envy has an integrated Intel gpu and an NVidia MX 250 dedicated gpu. These folders are located in some snap applications ( Pinta and pyqt5-runtime ) as well as in usr/share. Is that because the kernel has so many drivers build in? Can I delete those folders? They are only small, but since they have have no use is it possible to get rid of them for good?And if yes, how? ( The snaps are mounted as loops and I don't seem to be able to unmount them.)

I run:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.5-051505-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB

in triple boot with Mint 20.2 Uma and Windows 10

Comment: I would leave these libraries alone. You are bound to get massive duplication using Snap - it's claimed as a feature for Snap.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jeremy. I'll just let them live there in peace. I was just wondering why they were there.